# Catching play event in video on mobile safari

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iOS app that contains a lot of local web content.  Some of that content is video/audio.  I have a click event attached to the video and audio tags that fires an analytics url that I'm going to catch in the UIWebView.  The problem is that click event doesn't register.  I'm assuming this is because iOS replaces the video with its own special movie player.  How do I catch the play event so I can do something with it.  Here's my jQuery code for the click event.

```
 function videoClick() {
    $("video").click(function () {
        alert("here");
        //document.location = "ignoretap:///";
        var videoTitle = $(this).attr("data-mediatitle");
        var videoSrc = $(this).children("source").attr("src");
        if (videoTitle != null && videoTitle.length > 0) {
            document.location = "analytics:///" + "page" + videoTitle;
        }
        else {
            document.location = "analytics:///" + "page" + videoSrc;
        }
    });
}
```

Here's my html for the video

```
 <video width="100%" controls="controls" data-mediatitle="testing">
      <source src="StoryOfIyal.mp4" type="video/mp4" poster="IyalVideo.htm-iyalvideoscreenshot_lg.jpg"></source>
      Your Browser does not support the video tag
 </video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  You have to bind to the "play" event in jQuery, not the click event.  Here's the updated function.

```
 function videoClick() {
    $("video").bind('play', function () {
        alert("here");
        //document.location = "ignoretap:///";
        var videoTitle = $(this).attr("data-mediatitle");
        var videoSrc = $(this).children("source").attr("src");
        if (videoTitle != null && videoTitle.length > 0) {
            document.location = "analytics:///" + "page" + videoTitle;
        }
        else {
            document.location = "analytics:///" + "page" + videoSrc;
        }
    });
}
```